# Is it possible to import several xml from different sites to another?

Tags: import

I already have one site running on wordpress, but there are other two I want to combine into this one without losing any content. Is the default import tool helpful in this scenario? I don't want to bring a xml file and find that the content was overriden or something. I need to have the current data, plus 2 sites' data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Core import/export tool will only add content, not overwrite or delete anything old.